# How to bind Mixed Json to Table in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, multidimensional-array

```
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : { "first" : "John", "last" : "Backus" }, "contribs" : [ "Fortran", "ALGOL", "Backus-Naur Form", "FP" ], "awards" : [            {              "award" : "W.W. McDowell Award",              "year" : 1967,              "by" : "IEEE Computer Society"            },            { "award" : "Draper Prize",              "year" : 1993,              "by" : "National Academy of Engineering"            } ] }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have take your JSON format and binded it in to table using ng-repeat.

ng repaet sample in html file:

```
<body ng-controller="Ctrl">
```

```
<tbody ng-repeat="dat in alldata">

  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">{{dat.name.first}} {{dat.name.last}}</td>

  </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="3" align="center"><span style="font-weight:bold">Contribution</span></td></tr>

  <tr ng-repeat="cont in dat.contribs">
    <td colspan="3">{{ cont}}</td>

  </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="3" align="center"><span style="font-weight:bold">Awards</span></td></tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="aw in dat.awards">
    <td>{{ aw.award}}</td>
        <td>{{ aw.year}}</td>
        <td>{{ aw.by}}</td>

  </tr>


</tbody>
```

Sample Script file:

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.alldata = [
   {  
   "_id":1,
   "name":{  
      "first":"John",
      "last":"Backus"
   },
   "contribs":[  
      "Fortran",
      "ALGOL",
      "Backus-Naur Form",
      "FP"
   ],
   "awards":[  
      {  
         "award":"W.W. McDowell Award",
         "year":1967,
         "by":"IEEE Computer Society"
      },
      {  
         "award":"Draper Prize",
         "year":1993,
         "by":"National Academy of Engineering"
      }
   ]
}
  ];
});
```

Please find the plnkr link for it: [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/207jaCHE4T2JLxdFeOWh?p=preview)

Comment: Can you please give me hrml format of table view,  it will help me to understand how you want to show it